# How to compile gRPC Proto files?

Tags: grpc, grpc-node, grpc-web

How to use the protoc command line program to compile a *.proto file to a certain language for all languages except for Node.

Answer (score 1):

`protoc` uses a plugin model for functionality including the functionality to generate language-specific stubs. `protoc` includes plugin functionality for several languages (e.g. Python, Java) out-of-the-box but, for others, Go, Rust etc., you'll need to follow additional instructions (e.g. for Go [compiling protobufs](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/gotutorial/#compiling-protocol-buffers); Rust has various choices including [Prost](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost)).

Unless you're a provider wishing to bundle language-specific stubs (as SDKs) alongside your protocol buffers, it's generally better to leave the generation of stubs to end developers. If you still wish to generate the stubs, it may be better to solicit your developers for the languages they need (and generate these stubs) rather than for all languages (the `protoc` team has a  [list of languages](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/third_party.md#programming-languages) for which plugins exist but this is likely incomplete).

If you're using gRPC and your protobufs include `service` and `rpc` definitions, you will need additional plugins and, in some instances (e.g. Python), to use a different mechanism ([Quick Start: Python](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Check and try.